# Regularity of the weak solution of the transport equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, transport-equation

Consider the following transport equation:
$$y_t(t,x)=y_x(t,x), \ \ (t,x)\in(0,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)
$$
with initial state $y(0,x)=y_0(x)\in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$.

By the method of characteristics, we can prove that the solution $y$ is given explicitly by $$y(t,x)=y_0(x+t).$$ Clearly, the solution have the same regularity of the initial state.i.e $y\in L^2((0,\infty)\times(\infty,\infty)).$ 
Now, by using the semigroup approach, we can prove that the derevative operator is skew-adjoint, and hence, it generates a group of linear operators. Furthermore, from the semigroup theory, we have the regularity:
$$y\in C(0,\infty;L^2(-\infty,\infty)).$$
My question: How $y$ can be continuous knowing that from the exact formula it doesn't?.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion from semigroup theory is that it is continuous in time, namely with domain $(0,\infty)$, with values in $L^2((-\infty,\infty))$.  In other words, for each $t \in (0,\infty)$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that 
$$
|t-s| < \delta \Rightarrow \Vert y(t,\cdot) - y(s,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2} < \epsilon.
$$
This is *not* the same thing as asserting that the solution $y$ is continuous in space and time, or even that $y(t,\cdot)$ is continuous in space for some $t$.

Now, from the solution generated by characteristics we actually have the same conclusion since 
$$
\Vert y(t,\cdot) - y(s,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2}^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |y(t,x) - y(s,x)|^2 dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |y_0(x + t) - y_0(x+s)|^2 dx \\
=  \int_{-\infty}^\infty |y_0(x+t-s) - y_0(x)|^2 dx,
$$
and so
$$
\Vert y(t,\cdot) - y(s,\cdot) \Vert_{L^2} = \Vert y_0(\cdot + t-s) - y_0 \Vert_{L^2}.
$$
Continuity in time then follows from continuity of translations in $L^2$, namely 
$$
\lim_{h \to 0 } \Vert f(\cdot +h) - f \Vert_{L^2} =0
$$
for $f \in L^2$.

Comment: Thank you sir. I belieave that we can do so of nitial states in $L^p$. If $p=\infty$, what kind of regularity we should expect?. Thanks

Comment: You will continuity in time with values in $L^p$ by swapping $2$ and $p$ in what I've written above.

Comment: Yes sir I see that thanks. What about the case $p=\infty$?.